# Saparate Sql Table column with slash and store value in new column

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a **Table** having **column1** with value **A/B** in numeric format. I want to separate value **B** ( / separated value) and store them in **column2** using SQL Query

Current Column

```
Column1
---------
1.201/1.207
2.512/2.651
```

I requred

```
Column1 |  Column2 
-------------------
1.201   |   1.207
2.512   |   2.651
```

Comment: `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE Table SET column2 = and something like SUBSTRING_INDEX('A/B', '/', -1)

See more on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index